# Constructing Quartic number fields

Tags: finite-fields, quartics

Let $Qrt(n)$ be the $n$th quartic field. For $n = 5$, the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ defines the quartic field $Qrt(5)$. What is the polynmial $P(x)$ of degree $4$ that defines the $13$th quartic field? In other words, for $Qrt(13)$, what is the smallest degree $4$ polynomial which defines that field? The discriminant of $P(x)$ should be $13^3$. Thanks for help.

Comment: What is *the $n$th quartic field*? I'm not aware of any enumeration of quartic fields. Admittedly that may say more about me than about the concept.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I mean, it's clearly possible to do. However, I am also unaware of any canonical, or even just nice, way to do it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree the notation doesn't make sense, but I suspect the OP is seeking the quartic subfield of the thirteenth cyclotomic field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following LStU's interpretation, about the polynomial generating the quartic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{13})$. Let $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{13}\right)$. Since $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(13\mathbb{Z})^*$ and the quartic residues in $\mathbb{Z}/(13\mathbb{Z})^*$ are $\{1,3,9\}$,
$$ \alpha = \omega+\omega^3+\omega^9 $$
$$ \beta = \omega^2+\omega^6+\omega^5 $$
$$ \gamma = \omega^4+\omega^{12}+\omega^{10} $$
$$ \delta = \omega^8+\omega^{11}+\omega^{7} $$
are algebraic conjugates and the quartic subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ is generated by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, namely $\color{blue}{x^4+x^3+2x^2-4x+3}$. The coefficients of this polynomial are simply found by evaluating the elementary symmetric polynomials of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$.